# Remove space between Card

Tags: flutter, dart, space, card

How to remove the column space between `Card` ?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sample"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Text("Card 1"),
          )),
          Card(
            child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), child: Text("Card 2")),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output**

[image: d]

Comment: You are getting the space between the cards because of the `padding` you applied to the cards.

Comment: @TimilehinJegede I have removed it, the space still there.

Comment: The `Card` widget has a default `margin`. Set it to zero by doing `margin: EdgeInsets.zero` @John Joe

Comment: @TimilehinJegede looks good ! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, the `card` widget has a default `margin` set to `4.0 logical pixels` , to eliminate the spaces, you can adjust the default `margin` to your preference:

I added a demo using your widget tree as an example:

```
Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    // set the margin to zero
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: Text("Card 1"),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    // set the margin to zero
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: Text(
                      "Card 2",
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you using. `padding: EdgeInsets.all(15)` in your card. You Can alloy padding only on the required sides.
In the card try adding `margin:EdgeInsets.zero`

```
 Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
     ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `default margin` in Flutter is 4.0 pixels on all sides. To change this set

```
margin: EdgeInsets.zero
```

To learn more about `margins` go [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card/margin.html)